# Substitute `1 ` with ` 1.`

Tags: python, regex

Suppose such a list

```
l = ['1\xa0My Cll to Adventure: 1949–1967',
 '2\xa0Crossing the Threshold: 1967–1979',
 '3\xa0My Abyss: 1979–1982',
 '4\xa0My Rod of Trils: 1983–1994',
 '5\xa0The Ultimte Boon: 1995–21',
 '6\xa0Returning the Boon: 211–215',
 '7\xa0My Lst Yer nd My Gretest Chllenge: 216–217',
 '8\xa0Looking Bck from  Higher Level']
```

The result I want is

```
[' 1.My Cll to Adventure: 1949–1967',
 ' 2.Crossing the Threshold: 1967–1979',
 ' 3.My Abyss: 1979–1982',
 ' 4.My Rod of Trils: 1983–1994',
 ' 5.The Ultimte Boon: 1995–21',
 ' 6.Returning the Boon: 211–215',
 ' 7.My Lst Yer nd My Gretest Chllenge: 216–217',
 ' 8.Looking Bck from  Higher Level']
```

I tried with codes

```
import re
In [114]: [re.sub(r'\d\xa0', r' \d.', i) for i in l]
Out[114]:
[' \\d.My Cll to Adventure: 1949–1967',
 ' \\d.Crossing the Threshold: 1967–1979',
 ' \\d.My Abyss: 1979–1982',
 ' \\d.My Rod of Trils: 1983–1994',
 ' \\d.The Ultimte Boon: 1995–21',
 ' \\d.Returning the Boon: 211–215',
 ' \\d.My Lst Yer nd My Gretest Chllenge: 216–217',
 ' \\d.Looking Bck from  Higher Level']
```

It failed to substitute with numerics as I intended.

How to accomplish such a task?

Comment: You'll need a capture group you can reference. `re.sub(r'(\d+)\xa0', r' \1.', i`

Comment: I don't understand your comments. I google `f's up` and get non-related topics. @MadPhysicist

Comment: @Computing. Sorry about that. The comment was a continuation of what Coldspeed was saying. It's also gestalt factually wrong because \x magically works even in raw strings according to the spec. The f in f's up was meant to represent the f-word. Hope that clears things up. I've deleted the comment now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't capturing the number that you want before the full stop. To do that we just need to use parentheses around the digits we want to capture and then reference them using their capture group id, which is `1`.

With:

```
l = ['1\xa0My Cll to Adventure: 1949–1967',
 '2\xa0Crossing the Threshold: 1967–1979',
 '3\xa0My Abyss: 1979–1982',
 '4\xa0My Rod of Trils: 1983–1994',
 '5\xa0The Ultimte Boon: 1995–21',
 '6\xa0Returning the Boon: 211–215',
 '7\xa0My Lst Yer nd My Gretest Chllenge: 216–217',
 '8\xa0Looking Bck from  Higher Level']
```

Then we run:

```
import re
[re.sub(r'(\d+)\xa0', r' \1.', i) for i in l]
```

and get the output:

```
[' 1.My Cll to Adventure: 1949–1967',
 ' 2.Crossing the Threshold: 1967–1979',
 ' 3.My Abyss: 1979–1982',
 ' 4.My Rod of Trils: 1983–1994',
 ' 5.The Ultimte Boon: 1995–21',
 ' 6.Returning the Boon: 211–215',
 ' 7.My Lst Yer nd My Gretest Chllenge: 216–217',
 ' 8.Looking Bck from  Higher Level']
```

Answer (score 1):

Following works using `string` `replace` method in a `for` loop:

```
outl = []
for i in l:
    outl.append(" "+i.replace("\xa0",".",1))
print(outl)
```

Output:

```
[' 1.My Cll to Adventure: 1949–1967', 
' 2.Crossing the Threshold: 1967–1979', 
' 3.My Abyss: 1979–1982', 
' 4.My Rod of Trils: 1983–1994', 
' 5.The Ultimte Boon: 1995–21', 
' 6.Returning the Boon: 211–215', 
' 7.My Lst Yer nd My Gretest Chllenge: 216–217', 
' 8.Looking Bck from  Higher Level']
```